# Сортировка массива из БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть вывод определенного списка из sql `Array("NAME"=>"ASC")`. Сортируется по имени по алфавиту. Вопрос: как сделать сортировку начиная с определенной буквы?

Comment: а остальные что будете делать?

Comment: остальные выводятся по алфавиту. т.е. сначала идут, например, на "Д", потом А,Б,В..Либо просто по ID

Answer (score 1):

```
select pole, IF( LEFT( pole, 1) = 'Д', 0, 1) specPole
from table
order by specPole, pole
```

Если значение поле насинается с `Д` тогда `specPole=0` и получается,
если поле начинается на `Д` оно сортируется первой, потом идут по стандарту другие значении